# PHP inside AJAX post call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

A PHP page contains a variable `$hash` and has a button. The button's click event is handled by jQuery. I want jQuery to do an AJAX call as follows:

```
$.post("testupdate.php",  {hash:"<?php echo $hash; ?>"} , function(data) {

           $("#body").html(data);
});
```

However, the PHP code `<?php echo $hash; ?>` inserted inside the AJAX call isn't working. How can I make it work please? Thanks.

---

Update: I made it work by inserting a script element in the html page which is processed before the jQuery call:

```
<script> var hash = "<?php echo $hash; ?>"; </script>
```

And then did the following in the jQuery function call:

```
$.post("testupdate.php",  {hashpost:hash} , function(data) {

           $("#body").html(data);
});
```

Comment: What is not working exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this..

```
<script>
var hash = '<?php echo $hash; ?>';
$.ajax({         
        url : "testupdate.php", 
        type: 'POST',  
        data: {'hash': hash},               
        success: function (response) {          
            console.log(response);          
        },
        error: function(request,  error , status) {
            console.log(error); 
        }       
    });
</script>
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by inserting a script element in the html page which is processed before the jQuery call:

```
<script> var hash = "<?php echo $hash; ?>"; </script>
```

And then did the following in the jQuery function call:

```
$.post("testupdate.php",  {hashpost:hash} , function(data) {

           $("#body").html(data);
});
```